# Validación "mayor que" o "menor que" en el request de laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

¿Cómo puedo hacer en el request de laravel, una validación que no permita grabar si un número en especifico es mayor a otro?

Por ejemplo: que el valor 1 no pueda ser menor que el valor 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una validación de ese tipo no existe en Laravel, debes crear una personalizada, en otras preguntas he puesto ejemplos de como hacerlo, sin embargo en esta ocasión voy a citar una [respuesta de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036882/laravel-validate-a-integer-field-that-need-to-be-greater-than-other), para no reinventar la rueda.

Defines el validador en el AppServiceProvider:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  public function boot()
  {
    Validator::extend('greater_than_field', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
      $min_field = $parameters[0];
      $data = $validator->getData();
      $min_value = $data[$min_field];
      return $value > $min_value;
    });   

    Validator::replacer('greater_than_field', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
      return str_replace(':field', $parameters[0], $message);
    });
  }
}
```

y lo usarías de esta forma:

```
$rules = [
  'initial_page' => 'required_with:end_page|integer|min:1|digits_between: 1,5',
  'end_page' => 'required_with:initial_page|integer|greater_than_field:initial_page|digits_between:1,5'
];
```

Comment: Utilicé tu respuesta y obtengo este error **Class 'App\Providers\Validator' not found**

Comment: agrega `use Validator;` para utilizar el facade.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request) {

$this->validate($request, [
    'valor1' => 'min:valor2'
]);

// Validación correcta ...
}
```

Puedes usar el validador de laravel, regla **min**. Añádelo al método del controlador que estés usando. Te pongo el método store como ejemplo.

Valor 2 sería un valor fijo o bien una variable que asignes.

En caso de que sea una variable sería así:

```
public function store(Request $request) {

$this->validate($request, [
    'valor1' => 'min:$valor2'
]);

// Validación correcta ...
}
```

Fuente: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-min