# Greater_than_field Request Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

En días anteriores hice esta pregunta [Validación "mayor que" o "menor que" en el request de laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/27876/validaci%c3%b3n-mayor-que-o-menor-que-en-el-request-de-laravel) para obtener una validación personalizada en laravel que funciono correctamente validando dos campos, pero quisiera saber si es posible realizar esta misma validación en una multiregistro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy validando que por cada registro, el campo **valor pagado** no sea mayor que el campo **valor factura** y lo estoy haciendo de esta manera:

```
public function rules()
{    
  $valor = count($this->get('valorFacturaPagoForwardDetalle'));

  for($i = 0; $i < $valor; $i++)
  {
   $validacion['valorPagadoPagoForwardDetalle'.$i] = 'required_with:valorFacturaPagoForwardDetalle'.$i.'|numeric|min:1';

   $validacion['valorFacturaPagoForwardDetalle'.$i] =  'required_with:valorPagadoPagoForwardDetalle'.$i.'|numeric|greater_than_field:valorPagadoPagoForwardDetalle'.$i;   
  }
  return $validacion;
}
```

No sé que error pueda tener pero el código pero no está funcionando esta validación.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código de la vista de la tabla? ¿La variable $valor está obteniendo el "valor" esperado?

Comment: La variable $valor solo obtiene el numero de veces que debe dar vueltas el for, si hay 4 registros el for se recorre 4 veces.

Comment: Bueno, realmente no respondiste ninguna de las dos preguntas. Me gustaría ver el código de la vista.

Comment: Pues en realidad el código de la vista es un poco extenso ...

Comment: En ese orden de ideas tendrías que revisar el código de la validación y hacer algo de debugging para ver como están llegando los valores.

Answer (score 0):

En tu vista, intenta generar un

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[$id]"
```

del tipo array.

Luego en tu controlador intentar obtenerlo también como un array:

```
$array = $request->get('id');
```

Luego procesarlo en un bucle:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
```

**Actualización:**

No es hidden. Debe llevar el nombre y el tipo de tu campo *valorFacturaPagoForwardDetalle*

Comment: ¿con qué fin agregar este campo?

Comment: No es hidden. Me equivoqué. Debe llevar el nombre y el tipo del campo.